# Get SharePoint online Term set and create term if does not exist in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

My term store hierarchy in SharePoint online admin:

```
Organisation             
  Org Units 
     Department 
       Test Facilities Management    
     Location  
       Test location
```

I would like to search for 'Test Facilities Management' only in 'Department' and create it under 'Department' if it does not exist.

I have the below PowerShell script below to check and create a term in SharePoint Online. But I would like to check **only** in 'Department' for the term. I am not having any success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$TermGroupName = "Organisation"
$TermSetName = "Org Units"
$TermName="Test Facilities Management"
If(-Not(Get-PnPTerm -Identity $TermName -TermSet $TermSetName -TermGroup $TermGroupName -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    #Create new Term
    New-PnPTerm -Name $TermName -TermSet $TermSetName -TermGroup $TermGroupName 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to create a subterm.
My test code for your reference:

```
$TermGroupName = "testMetaData"#Group
$TermSetName = "test"#term group
$TermName="test1"#term set
$subTermName="subTerm"#subterm
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$term=Get-PnPTerm -Identity $TermName -TermSet $TermSetName -TermGroup $TermGroupName -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
$subterm=Get-PnPTerm -Identity $subTermName -TermSet $TermSetName -TermGroup $TermGroupName -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($subterm.Name -eq $null){
  $guid=New-Guid
  $term.CreateTerm($subTermName, 1033, $guid)
  $ctx.Load($term)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Comment: That solved part of the question which is creating a subTermName under a term. Is there a way to search for a sub term in a term? like find 'Test Facilities Management' in 'department' term only. The recursive flag will search for a term in all the TermSetName.

Comment: There is no oob api to get sunterm.We may need to get parent term firstly,then loop traversalthe terms attribute of the parent term.